# Flutter: Unhandled exception: MissingPluginException - with all libraries

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

i got this problem with all libraries
admob flutter / native admob flutter / sharedprefrences / google mobile ads / permissions

```
    Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.

Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(21463): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51510/VRqSC9lk_-c=/ws
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86 arm...
I/OpenGLRenderer(21463): Davey! duration=716ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=34252982492120, Vsync=34253282492108, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=34253288467940, AnimationStart=34253288528840, PerformTraversalsStart=34253288729740, DrawStart=34253322878740, SyncQueued=34253323564640, SyncStart=34253327790140, IssueDrawCommandsStart=34253327886740, SwapBuffers=34253367358840, FrameCompleted=34253703365940, DequeueBufferDuration=225435700, QueueBufferDuration=9521200, GpuCompleted=43984843964424, 

E/flutter (21463): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method initController on channel flutter_native_admob)

E/flutter (21463): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:154:7)
E/flutter (21463): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21463): 

E/flutter (21463): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method setAdUnitID on channel [#053e2])
E/flutter (21463): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:154:7)
E/flutter (21463): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21463): 
E/flutter (21463): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method initController on channel flutter_native_admob)

E/flutter (21463): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:154:7)
E/flutter (21463): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21463): 
E/flutter (21463): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method setAdUnitID on channel [#bca11])

E/flutter (21463): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:154:7)
E/flutter (21463): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21463): 

E/flutter (21463): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method initController on channel flutter_native_admob)
E/flutter (21463): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:154:7)
E/flutter (21463): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21463): 
E/flutter (21463): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method setAdUnitID on channel [#716dc])
E/flutter (21463): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:154:7)
E/flutter (21463): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21463): 
E/flutter (21463): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method loadBannerAd on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_mobile_ads)
E/flutter (21463): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:154:7)
E/flutter (21463): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21463): #1      BannerAd.load (package:google_mobile_ads/src/ad_containers.dart:554:5)
E/flutter (21463): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21463): 
E/flutter (21463): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to create a platform view of unregistered type: plugins.flutter.io/google_mobile_ads/ad_widget
E/flutter (21463):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createAndroidViewForPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:142)
E/flutter (21463):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:104)
E/flutter (21463):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:59)
E/flutter (21463):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/flutter (21463):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:84)
E/flutter (21463):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:869)
E/flutter (21463):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter (21463):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
E/flutter (21463):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
E/flutter (21463):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/flutter (21463):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (21463):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/flutter (21463):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
E/flutter (21463): , null, null)
E/flutter (21463): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
E/flutter (21463): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:18)
E/flutter (21463): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21463): #2      AndroidViewController.create (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:771:5)
E/flutter (21463): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21463): 
E/flutter (21463): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method loadBannerAd on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_mobile_ads)
E/flutter (21463): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:154:7)
E/flutter (21463): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21463): #1      BannerAd.load (package:google_mobile_ads/src/ad_containers.dart:554:5)
E/flutter (21463): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21463): 
E/flutter (21463): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to create a platform view of unregistered type: plugins.flutter.io/google_mobile_ads/ad_widget
E/flutter (21463):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createAndroidViewForPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:142)
E/flutter (21463):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:104)
E/flutter (21463):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:59)
E/flutter (21463):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/flutter (21463):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:84)
E/flutter (21463):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:869)
E/flutter (21463):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter (21463):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
E/flutter (21463):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
E/flutter (21463):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/flutter (21463):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (21463):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/flutter (21463):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
E/flutter (21463): , null, null)
E/flutter (21463): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
E/flutter (21463): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:18)
E/flutter (21463): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21463): #2      AndroidViewController.create (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:771:5)
E/flutter (21463): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21463): 
E/flutter (21463): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method checkPermissionStatus on channel flutter.baseflow.com/permissions/methods)
E/flutter (21463): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:154:7)
E/flutter (21463): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21463): #1      MethodChannelPermissionHandler.checkPermissionStatus (package:permission_handler_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_permission_handler.dart:16:20)
E/flutter (21463): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21463): #2      FuturePermissionStatusGetters.isGranted (package:permission_handler_platform_interface/src/permission_status.dart:90:40)
E/flutter (21463): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21463): #3      Provaiderdownload.permision (package:bac_1/Providers.dart:178:9)
E/flutter (21463): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21463): #4      _itemPageState.downloadFile (package:bac_1/ItemPage.dart:239:9)
E/flutter (21463): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21463):
```

after i add this code to MainActivity.ky the sharedpreferences problem gone , but I got the same problem with all libraries

```
    import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(SharedPreferencesPlugin())

    }
}
```

this is my App/build.gradle file

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.bac_1"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false

            useProguard true
            proguardFiles(
                    getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' //enter the latest version
    //add them
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.5.0'
    def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"
}
android {
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

and this my android/build.gradle file

```
 buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

i find this solution
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4jU5.png)

but i got this error

```
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
E/AndroidRuntime(22103): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(22103): Process: com.example.bac_1, PID: 22103
E/AndroidRuntime(22103): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/reward/RewardedVideoAdListener;
E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at com.shatsy.admobflutter.AdmobFlutterPlugin.<clinit>(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at com.shatsy.admobflutter.AdmobFlutterPlugin.registerWith(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:21)
E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at com.example.bac_1.MainActivity.configureFlutterEngine(MainActivity.kt:9)
E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onAttach(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:187)
E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onCreate(FlutterActivity.java:459)
E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
E/AndroidRuntime(22103): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAdListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~BBlCShaDm-m3tPK2oAlhSA==/com.example.bac_1-JIITURh6vmNBNhcQBJ3w7w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~BBlCShaDm-m3tPK2oAlhSA==/com.example.bac_1-JIITURh6vmNBNhcQBJ3w7w==/lib/x86, /data/app/~~BBlCShaDm-m3tPK2oAlhSA==/com.example.bac_1-JIITURh6vmNBNhcQBJ3w7w==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    ... 21 more
```

Comment: have you tried deleting your `generated_plugin_registrant` file and  and try running `flutter clean` and `flutter create .`

Comment: sorry but this not working

Answer (score 0):

After adding library, you should stop session and run app again to successfully import plugins to your app. Plugins need to install when app is generated.

Comment: yes i tried it befire and nothinf changes,    i don't know whats the problem , but I think that the solution is in MainACtivity.kt bcz I solved the same problem od sharedpreferences with the code I mentioned in the problem in the top

Comment: the problem that all thing was ok, but Suddenly this error occurred